# Website menu doesn't scroll on phones

Tags: bootstrap-modal

I have Problem with Scrolling with my website on my phone

Here have i link of my [website](http://www.ekizceliler.com/)

If you opened website with phone then can you not scrolling in Menu.

For more info about my problem I added this text:

I made a screenshot on my phone the menu scroll work not that is my problem. [Screenshot Link](http://i66.tinypic.com/2yxrzeo.png) under Tarih is more links but i can not scroll to down.

is there no one can help me with fixing ? i needed mobile friendly menu and website... www.ekizceliler.com

if you read website with phone than can you see that menu doesn't scroll on phones

but website scrolled good.

Please help me.. I needed finished this website?

Regards...

Comment: You have used nav bar but i guess you don't have mentioned what to do on small screen properly. as if you click on any link and come back from navigation bar it works perfect.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. it works perfect but only problem is Menu with using in mobile android if i want scroll to down for other links that work not the page scroll to down.
I know i needed a code but which code that is my problem maybe can you download the page on your computer so that you can fixed css bootstrap.min or style codes ???

regards.

Comment: I made a screenshot on my phone the menu scroll work not that is my problem. http://i66.tinypic.com/2yxrzeo.png under Tarih is more links but i can not scroll to down.

Comment: is there no one can help me with fixing ? i needed mobile friendly menu and website... http://www.ekizceliler.com

if you read website with phone than can you see that menu doesn't scroll on phones

but website scrolled good.

Please help me.. I needed finished this website?

Regards..